# bootstrap table-bordered remove horizontal line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to remove the bootstrap table-bordered horizontal line and keep the vertical line.

I have tried many solutions and done many of the research but I still cannot find the solution.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@TwBootstrap</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add these css rules in your css file (remove the border from the `td` and add again to the right side):

```
.table-bordered td {border: none !important; border-right: solid 1px #ccc !important;}
```

```css
.table-bordered td {
  border: none !important;
  border-right: solid 1px #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@TwBootstrap</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One more snippet to remove the border from `thead` also...

```css
.table-bordered td,
.table-bordered th {
  border: none !important;
  border-right: solid 1px #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@TwBootstrap</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is near to what I am trying to do but there is a border-bottom horizontal line below the "first name" & "last name". Is that possible to remove that border-bottom line?

Answer (score 3):

This CSS should to the trick:

```
.table {border: 1px solid black!important;} 
.table tr, .table td, .table th {border: 0!important;}
.table tr td:nth-child(2), 
.table tr th:nth-child(2) {border-left: 1px solid black!important;}
```

If you want to support tables with more than 2 columns:

```
.table {border: 1px solid black!important;} 
.table tr, .table td, .table th {border: 0!important;}
.table tr td, 
.table tr th {border-left: 1px solid black!important;}
.table tr td:nth-child(1), 
.table tr th:nth-child(1) {border-left: 0!important;}
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKbJNV

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this in css if you really want to use table-bordered class..

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
    .table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
    .table-bordered {
        border-bottom:0;
        border-top: 0;
    }
```