# Bootstrap table with borders only on the inside

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-modal

I wish to create a table with Bootstrap but the table must have borders only on the inside. Have some ideas?
If it is possible I don't wish to use css but only html and Bootstrap.
Thank you.

At the end I wish to implement this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdiZg.jpg)

Comment: give some idea what you want ot implement

Comment: what do you mean by borders on inside ?

Comment: I have added a figure

Comment: ` borders on inside` I mean that inside on the table the are the borders to divide the cell but the borders of the table are invisible like at the figure that I have added now

Comment: I am afraid you will have to use CSS. It can't be done with html and bootstrap as far as I know. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504960/bootstrap-table-bordered-remove-horizontal-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Which bootstrap are you using? 3 or 4?

Comment: And is there a way to use divider or separator? Because I use a lot of bootstrap

Comment: I use Bootstrap 4 but I can change there is not a relevant problem

Comment: No its possible with 4. Thats why i asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very cumbersome, but this is the best I got.
USe bootstrap's border utility classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Overlay</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <table class="table" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="border-top-0 border-right border-bottom-0">#</th>
      <th scope="col" class="border-top-0 border-right border-bottom-0">First</th>
      <th scope="col" class="border-top-0 border-right border-bottom-0">Last</th>
      <th scope="col" class="border-top-0 border-right border-bottom-0 border-right-0">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" class="border-right border-bottom-0">1</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0"> Mark</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0">Otto</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0 border-right-0">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" class="border-right border-bottom-0">1</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0"> Mark</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0">Otto</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0 border-right-0">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" class="border-right border-bottom-0">1</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0"> Mark</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0">Otto</td>
      <td class="border-right border-bottom-0 border-right-0">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fy5t2r91/)

Comment: Is it possibile to use  Bootstrap 3.3.7? Because I have tried to do it with also Bootstrap 3.3.7 but it doesn't work

Comment: No, these border utility classes exist in bootstrap 4 only.